# Serialized object password

Tags: vb.net, serialization, visual-studio-2012, passwords, cryptography

I am serializing an object in Visual Basic.net and saving this object to file. In this process I am using a CryptoStream to encrypt the object with a password. My question is this: What is the best way to check if the password is correct or not?

Should I just check for the error number to see if it is the number returned when an incorrect password as used, or is there a specific function that can be used to determine if the correct password has been used?

Answer (score 0):

Ciphers don't have any concept of "correct" or "incorrect" keys – they simply transform some data into other data depending on the key. Every transformation is as "correct" as any other from the point of view of the cipher.

You could simply try to parse the data and catch errors that occur when the data is invalid. This is a fairly common approach, but in this case you need to make the parsing code very robust. It's also impossible to differentiate between corruption and a wrong password, which may be a user interface issue.

Another approach would be to use some kind of message authentication. A fairly straightforward choice would be [GCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode) if you have access to it. Manually applying [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code) to the ciphertext requires more planning, but should be possible. It's a bit more difficult, as you have to use different keys for the cipher and the MAC.